# A function to search a string and return all values after a special character

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, function, bots

I'm making a bot that scans a string input for stock tickers and returns the current price. The format would be !{ticker} e.g !AAPL

The function I currently have is:

```
function getVals(comment){
    let n = comment.indexOf("!")
    //Check if value
    if(n > 0){
        let ticker = comment.substring(n +1, n+5);

        //Then perform price check with ticker

    } else{
    console.log("error")
}
};

//Example comment
getVals("This if my first ticker !AAPL I also want to know !EA");
```

The issue's I have are:

1. The code only scans for 4 characters after the "!". I'm not sure how to end before a white space
2. The code executes after the first result, instead of scanning for remaining tickers.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Regexp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to achieve this.

```js
const str = 'This if my first ticker !AAPL I also want to know !EA';

const regexp = /![A-Z]+/g;

const result = str.match(regexp);

// Matches with '!' char
console.log(str.match(regexp));

// Removes '!' char
console.log(str.match(regexp).map((val)=>val.slice(1)));
```